# Prove that $f(x,y,z)=x^2 y+2xz^2$ is continuous at $(1,1,1)$

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

This is what I have so far (note this is scratch work):

We have,

$$
\begin{align}
\rvert f(x,y,z)-f(1,1,1)\lvert &=\lvert x^2 y+2xz^2-3\lvert\\
&=\lvert x^2y-y+y-1+2xz^2-2x+2x-2\lvert\\
&\leq \lvert y\lvert\lvert x^2-1\lvert+\lvert y-1\lvert+2\lvert zx\lvert 
\lvert z-1\lvert+2\lvert x-1\lvert\\
&=\lvert y\lvert\lvert x-1\lvert\lvert x+1\lvert+\lvert y-1\lvert+2\lvert zx\lvert 
\lvert z-1\lvert+2\lvert x-1\lvert\\
&< \lvert y\lvert\lvert x+1\lvert \delta+\:\delta\: + 2\delta\lvert z\lvert\lvert x\lvert+\:2\delta\\
\end{align}
$$
This is were I am stuck. I know that since $x-1<\delta$, $y-1<\delta$, and $z-1<\delta$ we can manipulate to have, $x<\delta+1$, $\:y<\delta+1$, $\:z<\delta+1$, $\:x+1<\delta+2.$ But this is just getting messy. I was thinking of defining $\delta$ to be a minimum but would it be a minimum of the deltas above?

Comment: You can try to prove that $g(x,y,z) = x^2 y$ and $h(x,y,z) = 2xz^2$ are continuous

Comment: Also, do you need to necessarily use the definition of continuity to prove it?

Comment: @LucasCorrêa I don't think we could assume (yet) that the sum of two continuous functions is continuous. If I've shown that if $g(x,y)$ and $h(x,y)$ are continuous, then their sum/product is continuous does that also extend to three variables? Or is that a separate proof?

Comment: Either way, in this case I have to show it using the definition of continuity.

Comment: Yeah, but if you still have not seen this result, forget what I said (the product in this case is not necessarily between scalar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extracting $\delta$, your expression is equal to
$$
\delta(|y||x+1| + 2|z||x| + 3)
$$
Now, if we say that $\delta$ will at most be chosen to be $1$ (there is nothing special about $1$, any value will do; I just like to use $1$), then we have
$$
|y||x+1|\leq 6\\
|z||x| \leq 4
$$
so we get
$$
\delta(|y||x+1| + 2|z||x| + 3) \leq \delta(6+8+3) = 17\delta
$$
Thus, choosing $\delta = \min\left(\frac{\epsilon}{17}, 1\right)$ will make sure that as long as
$$
|x-1|, |y-1|, |z-1| < \delta
$$
we have
$$
|f(x, y, z) - f(1, 1, 1)| < \epsilon
$$

---

Note, however, that this isn't exactly the definition of continuity. The definition of continuity is that for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that for any $x, y, z$ with
$$
\sqrt{(x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2 + (z-1)^2}<\delta
$$
we have
$$
|f(x, y, z) - f(1, 1, 1)|<\epsilon
$$
You are picking $x, y, z$ from a cube centered around $(1,1,1)$, while the definition wants you to use a *ball*. In order to apply the above proof to the actual definition you will have to check that this doesn't lead to any kind of problems.

Comment: By leading to any kind of problems do you mean isolated points?

Comment: @TomásPalamás No, it's somewhat simpler than that. I mean that the definition of continuity asks you to find a ball, while you are finding a cube. You have to make sure that that is good enough.

Comment: No reason your neighborhood can't be a cube.  You have freedom to choose your metric.  You can say $d((x,y,z),(1,1,1)) = \max (|x-1|,|y-1|,|z-1|).$  Anyway, in the standard metric, $\sqrt{(x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2 + (z-1)^2} < \delta \implies |x-1|, |y-1|, |z-1|< \delta$

Comment: @Arthur I think you forgot a $\delta.$ So it should be $\text{min}\{\frac{\epsilon}{14},1\}.$

Comment: Nevermind, I see what you did.

Comment: But shouldn't $2\lvert x\lvert\lvert z\lvert \leq 8$?

Comment: @TomàsPalamàs Yes, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can attack this from a rather different direction.

This set of elementary functions: $f(x,y,z) = x, g(x,y,z) = y,h(x,y,z) = z, c(x,y,z) = 1$ are all continuous.

Since the sum of continuous functions are continuous and the product of continuous functions are continuous, polynomials are continuous.

$p(x,y,z) = x^2y + 2xz^2$ is a polynomial.

QED

From what you have.

$d((x,y,z),(1,1,1)) < \delta \implies |f(x,y,z)- f(1,1,1)|< \delta||y(x+1)| + 3 + 2|xz||$

If $||y(x+1)| + 3 + 2|xz||$ is bounded, i.e. $||y(x+1)| + 3 + 2|xz|| < M$ then you can set  $\delta = \frac {\epsilon}{M}$

Nothing keeps us from saying $\delta \le 1$ therefore $||y(x+1)| + 3 + 2|xz||\le 17$

$\delta = \min(\frac {\epsilon}{17}, 1)$